# Problem while saving data using linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I have a class in c# with properties Name string, Questions List (Or array of questions), OptionType string. I need to save this data to sql server table. I'm using Linq-to-Sql.

I tried creating a stored procedure with table valued parameters for saving array of data, but unfortunately linq to sql doesn't support tvp.
Did anyone implemented such scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us what you've tried, what isn't working and expected output so we can further help you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume question list is a relational table in your sql if that's the case then save the question list first and then save the main class, after calling save method of linq you should be able to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the answer is no. If you really want to go that way then you can combine them and split them inside the stored procedure.

```
string[] s = { "a", "b" };
string s2 = string.Join("#", s);
```

the other answer with separate saves would be more nice though.